# How to change awesome fonts?

Tags: html, css

I found a Colourful Flower Popup Menu on Internet ([Click here](https://codepen.io/jasperlachance/pen/yOJdRr)) which is programmed by HTML and CSS. I want to change the "bars" and use of "bolt". How can I do it?
I think the original code does not use of awesome fonts.

[image]

CSS codes:

```
body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background: #596778;
   color: #EEEEEE;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
   body {
      padding: 170px 0 0 0;
      width: 100%
   }
}

a {
   color: inherit;
}

.menu-item,
.menu-open-button {
   background: #EEEEEE;
   border-radius: 100%;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   margin-left: -40px;
   position: absolute;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 80px;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
   transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
   transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
   transition: transform ease-out 200ms, -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
}

.menu-open {
   display: none;
}

.lines {
   width: 25px;
   height: 3px;
   background: #596778;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -12.5px;
   margin-top: -1.5px;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
   transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
   transition: transform 200ms;
   transition: transform 200ms, -webkit-transform 200ms;
}

.line-1 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
}

.line-2 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.line-3 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-1 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-2 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-3 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu {
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   text-align: center;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 26px;
}


/* .menu-item {
   transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
} */

.menu-item:hover {
   background: #EEEEEE;
   color: #3290B1;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(8) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(9) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-open-button {
   z-index: 2;
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
   transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
   -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
   transition-duration: 400ms;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   cursor: pointer;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button {
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
   transition-timing-function: linear;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
   transition-duration: 200ms;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item {
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
   transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
   transition-duration: 180ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.08361px, -104.99997px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0.08361px, -104.99997px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
   transition-duration: 280ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 280ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(90.9466px, -52.47586px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(90.9466px, -52.47586px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
   transition-duration: 380ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 380ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(90.9466px, 52.47586px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(90.9466px, 52.47586px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
   transition-duration: 480ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 480ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.08361px, 104.99997px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0.08361px, 104.99997px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(7) {
   transition-duration: 580ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 580ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-90.86291px, 52.62064px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-90.86291px, 52.62064px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(8) {
   transition-duration: 680ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 680ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-91.03006px, -52.33095px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-91.03006px, -52.33095px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(9) {
   transition-duration: 780ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 780ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-0.25084px, -104.9997px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-0.25084px, -104.9997px, 0);
}

.blue {
   background-color: #669AE1;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.blue:hover {
   color: #669AE1;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.green {
   background-color: #70CC72;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.green:hover {
   color: #70CC72;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.red {
   background-color: #FE4365;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.red:hover {
   color: #FE4365;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.purple {
   background-color: #C49CDE;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.purple:hover {
   color: #C49CDE;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.orange {
   background-color: #FC913A;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.orange:hover {
   color: #FC913A;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.lightblue {
   background-color: #62C2E4;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.lightblue:hover {
   color: #62C2E4;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.credit {
   margin: 24px 20px 120px 0;
   text-align: right;
   color: #EEEEEE;
}

.credit a {
   padding: 8px 0;
   color: #C49CDE;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.credit a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML codes:

```
<nav class="menu">
   <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open" />
   <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
    <span class="lines line-1"></span>
    <span class="lines line-2"></span>
    <span class="lines line-3"></span>
  </label>

   <a href="#" class="menu-item blue"> <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item green"> <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item red"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item purple"> <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item orange"> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item lightblue"> <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> </a>
</nav>
```

thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l26OL.jpg)

Comment: why do you need to use "awesome font"? You only want to change the "icon" - then change it

Comment: The contents of `<label class="menu-open-button">` make up the "bar", and they are animated on the check of checkbox. You will need to add your "bolt" icon there yourself, check if its available in a `fontawesome` library or use an image/svg

Comment: @TalRofe Thanks. How can I change it?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Thanks. That's right. My problem is that the "bars" isn't an icon or awesome font. In fact, the codes make three lines as "bars". How can I replace it by awesome font "bolt"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the 3 lines with a FontAwesome icon you want (bolt in this case):

From this:

```
   <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
     <span class="lines line-1"></span>
     <span class="lines line-2"></span>
     <span class="lines line-3"></span>
   </label>
```

To this:

```
<label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-bolt" style="color: black;"></i>
</label>
```

Notice the inline style I added for the FA icon. For some reason (likely your CSS with something on **<li>** that I didn't track down), it was showing as white; had to add that to make it pop out.

Here is the [almost] full modified code with FA CDN linked:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<nav class="menu">
  <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open" />
  <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
     <i class="fa-solid fa-bolt" style="color: black;"></i>
  </label>

  <a href="#" class="menu-item blue"> <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item green"> <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item red"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item purple"> <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item orange"> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item lightblue"> <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> </a>
</nav>
```